# Bolding equations in Google Docs (rather than LaTeX)?

Tags: google-docs

I started writing a lengthy theoretical physics paper in Google Docs using the basic equation editor (I was advised not to use LaTeX for this undergrad project). I know about the add-on that converts LaTeX to equations, but all I need to do that I can't already do is to bold and/or italicize things like vectors.

Can this be done or do I need to use the LaTeX add-on?

Answer (score 4):

The only method I have found is to use "Insert / Special Character", where they have bold versions of all latin and green letters. The keyword to find these bold versions is "MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC SMALL", or simply "MATHEMATICAL BOLD". There are several versions of bold for each letter. I always use "MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC SMALL y". This solution is not perfect, but it is the only one that I have managed to find so far.